# Extract tags from json datastructures using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have multiple JSON files like these:

```
{
  "object1": {
    "tags": ["A"],

    "something": "else",
    "other": "data"
  },
  "object2": {
    "tags": ["A", "B"]
  }
}
```

and

```
{
  "object3": {
    "tags": ["C"],

    "something": "else",
    "other": "data"
  },
  "object4": {
    "tags": ["A"]
  }
}
```

It is guaranteed that keys of all the objects (`object1` - `object4`) are unique, across all files.

I need to generate a different json file, that would be an array of used `tag`s, and each tag would have extra information which `object`s use it:

```
[
  { 
    "tag": "A",
    "objects": ["object1", "object2", "object4"]
  },
  { 
    "tag": "B",
    "objects": ["object2"]
  },
  { 
    "tag": "C",
    "objects": ["object3"]
  }
]
```

Order of tags in this output array is irrelevant.

So far I have: `cat *.json | jq -s add | jq '[.[].tags[]] | unique'` which gives me array of tags used across all files, but I don't quite know how to get the list of `object`s for those tags. I suspect that this is not a right approach, because I am loosing some information (source of the tag) during this transformation.

Any help with `jq` expressions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to `reduce` the input using `to_entries`

```sh
jq -s '
  add | reduce to_entries[] as $e ({}; .[$e.value.tags[]] += [$e.key])
' *.json
```

which would give you a structure like this

```json
{
  "A": [
    "object1",
    "object2",
    "object4"
  ],
  "B": [
    "object2"
  ],
  "C": [
    "object3"
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/qj8_iMHFS4)

To then convert this into your desired structure, append another `to_entries`

```sh
jq -s '
  add | reduce to_entries[] as $e ({}; .[$e.value.tags[]] += [$e.key])
  | to_entries | map({tag:.key, objects:.value})
' *.json
```

```json
[
  {
    "tag": "A",
    "objects": [
      "object1",
      "object2",
      "object4"
    ]
  },
  {
    "tag": "B",
    "objects": [
      "object2"
    ]
  },
  {
    "tag": "C",
    "objects": [
      "object3"
    ]
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/k0TFOPpAKm)